# Is there a way to do this in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
data = {'State': ['24', '24', '24', 
                  '24','24','24','24','24','24','24','24','24'],
        'County code': ['001', '001', '001', 
                        '001','002','002','002','002','003','003','003','003'],
        'TT code': ['123', '123', '123',
                    '123','124','124','124','124','125','125','125','125'],
        'BLK code': ['221', '221', '221',
                     '221','222','222','222','222','223','223','223','223'],
        'Age Code': ['1', '1', '2', '2','2','2','2','2','2','1','2','1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

essentially I want to just have where only the TT code where the age code is 2 and there are no 1's.  So I just want to have the data frame where:

```
'State': ['24', '24', '24', '24'],
'County code': ['002','002','002','002',],
'TT code': ['124','124','124','124',],
'BLK code': ['222','222','222','222'],
'Age Code': ['2','2','2','2']
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df = df[df['Age Code' == '2']]`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please have a look at the pandas [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) documentation and update your question with a [mcve] showing what you've tried and what went wrong with your attempts so that we can provide more specific answers than "Yes, there is a way to do this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to keep only the TT groups where there are only Age groups with value '2'?

You can use a `groupby.tranform('all')` on the boolean Series:

```
df[df['Age Code'].eq('2').groupby(df['TT code']).transform('all')]
```

output:

```
  State County code TT code BLK code Age Code
4    24         002     124      222        2
5    24         002     124      222        2
6    24         002     124      222        2
7    24         002     124      222        2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df111['Age Code'] = "2"
```

I am just wondering why the choice of string for valueType of integer